# AngularJs bind an Array to an checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays, checkbox

i have the following JS and HTML:

```js
$scope.loadInstallation = function (installationid) {
    $scope.currentInstallation = {};
    $scope.currentInstallation = $scope.installationList[installationid];;
    $scope.currentInstallationID = installationid;
};
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="installationmoduleIdList1">Module 1:</label>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="installationmoduleIdList1" ng-model="currentInstallation.moduleIdList" /></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="installationmoduleIdList2">Module 2:</label>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="installationmoduleIdList2" ng-model="currentInstallation.moduleIdList" /></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="installationmoduleIdList3">Module 3:</label>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="installationmoduleIdList3" ng-model="currentInstallation.moduleIdList" /></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="installationmoduleIdList4">Module 4:</label>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="installationmoduleIdList4" ng-model="currentInstallation.moduleIdList" /></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="installationmoduleIdList5">Module 5:</label>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="installationmoduleIdList5" ng-model="currentInstallation.moduleIdList" /></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="installationmoduleIdList6">Module 6:</label>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="installationmoduleIdList6" ng-model="currentInstallation.moduleIdList" /></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And an JSON, which look something like this:

```
currentInstallation =
{
  "id":"1",
  "moduleIdList": [ "1", "2" ]
}
```

The "1" in the "moduleIdList" equals "true" in the HTML "Module 1:" Checkbox, the Problem is, I don't know, how to bind the "moduleIdList" to the Checkboxes, so that when there's a "1" in "moduleIdList" the Checkbox is checked and when someone uncheck it, the "1" will be deleted out of the Array

Hope you can understand my problem, I'm glad for any help!

Greetings,
Simon

Comment: it seems to me, that just by using default `ng-model` -> it's impossible. Probably, the way to do it is to change your `moduleIdList` array

Comment: Yeah, I know, that it is not workign with ng-model, so I'm looking for an work around, because unfortunately I can't change the moduelIdList array

Comment: Simple work around is to implement in your `Controller` function that will convert from and to correct version of `moduleIdList` your models. That's all. Ordinary `for-loop`

Comment: I will try this, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got an workaround, which is fine for me.
I just don't use the ng-model, instead I use ng-checked ng-click, so I can use functions, which will do exactly what I want:

```js
$scope.loadInstallation = function (installationid) {
    $scope.currentInstallation = {};
    $scope.currentInstallation = $scope.installationList[installationid];;
    $scope.currentInstallationID = installationid;
};

$scope.isModuleSelected = function (id) {
    if ($scope.currentInstallation.moduleIdList != null && $scope.currentInstallation.moduleIdList.indexOf(id) != -1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
};

$scope.toggleModule = function (id) {
    if ($scope.currentInstallation.moduleIdList == null)
           $scope.currentInstallation.moduleIdList = [];
    var numberOnIndex = $scope.currentInstallation.moduleIdList.indexOf(id);
    if (numberOnIndex == -1)
        $scope.currentInstallation.moduleIdList.push(id);
    else 
        $scope.currentInstallation.moduleIdList.splice(numberOnIndex, 1);
};
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="installationmoduleIdList1">Module 1:</label>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="installationmoduleIdList1" ng-checked="isModuleSelected('1')" ng-click="toggleModule('1')" /></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="installationmoduleIdList2">Module 2:</label>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="installationmoduleIdList2" ng-checked="isModuleSelected('2')" ng-click="toggleModule('2')" /></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="installationmoduleIdList3">Module 3:</label>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="installationmoduleIdList3" ng-checked="isModuleSelected('3')" ng-click="toggleModule('3')" /></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="installationmoduleIdList4">Module 4:</label>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="installationmoduleIdList4" ng-checked="isModuleSelected('4')" ng-click="toggleModule('4')" /></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="installationmoduleIdList5">Module 5:</label>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="installationmoduleIdList5" ng-checked="isModuleSelected('5')" ng-click="toggleModule('5')" /></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="installationmoduleIdList6">Module 6:</label>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="installationmoduleIdList6" ng-checked="isModuleSelected('6')" ng-click="toggleModule('6')" /></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```